# How can I remove the fragment identifier from a URL?

Tags: python, string

I have a string containing a link. The link often has the form:

> http://www.address.com/something#something

Is there a function in python that can remove "#something" from a link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `split()`

```
>>> foo = "http://www.address.com/something#something"
>>> foo = foo.split('#')[0]
>>> foo
'http://www.address.com/something'
>>>
```

Answer (score 40):

For Python 2 use [urlparse.urldefrag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urldefrag):

```
>>> urlparse.urldefrag("http://www.address.com/something#something")
('http://www.address.com/something', 'something')
```

Answer (score 13):

In Python 3, the [`urldefrag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urldefrag) function is now part of [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```py
from urllib.parse import urldefrag
unfragmented = urldefrag("http://www.address.com/something#something")
```

Result:

```py
('http://www.address.com/something', 'something')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> s="http://www.address.com/something#something"
>>> s1=s.split("#")[0]
>>> s1
'http://www.address.com/something'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign away the unwanted part like so

```
fixed, throwaway = urldefrag(url)
```

where url is the fragmented address. This is a bit nicer than a split. I have not checked if it is faster or more efficient though.